# Why do seeing Devas, Yaksas, Raksasas, Gandharvas is obstruction to an yogi?

Tags: yoga

Vayu purana says that seeing Devas, Yaksas, Raksasas, Gandharvas etc., is a sign of obstruction to yoga.

Why is it? All of them are divine beings and why it can't be a sign of yoga instead of sign for disturbance to an yogi?

Comment: I have not seen the text, but the reason seems simple.The goal of yoga is the union with the Supreme Self.All else can create distractions and make the yogi feel that he has reache d or come near to the goal.Panptanjali also mentions that some 'Alaukika- experience is required just to convince the aspirant that therevIS a world beyond normal perception,But its role ends there.

Comment: because the mind will become enamoured with seeing these different visions rather than pushing on to the ultimate.